# Finding a subring of $M(2,\mathbb{Q})$ which is isomorphic to a) $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ b)$\mathbb{Q}$ c)$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2)}$.

Tags: ring-theory

I got this classwork but got very confused with the form of answer the question needs, Can anyone please help? Thank you